# Regex equivalence yield error

Tags: php, regex

Are these two regexp equivalent, except that second don't capture `dpthd` text?

```
'/<a name="dpthd_.*><\/a><a.*><\/a><a.*><\/a><h3.*>(.*)<\/h3>(.*)\s*(dpthd)/sU'

'/<a name="dpthd_.*><\/a><a.*><\/a><a.*><\/a><h3.*>(.*)<\/h3>(.*)\s*dpthd/sU'
```

I just removed parenthesis.

The problem is that the first don't work, and the second works fine

EDIT>>>>

`s (PCRE_DOTALL)
    If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.`

EDIT>>>>

Ok, I don't know what was a problem, I added `m` modifier and use preg_match_all now

```
preg_match_all('/<a name="dpthd_.*><\/a><a.*><\/a><a.*><\/a><h3.*>(.*)<\/h3>(.*)(?:<a name="dpthd_.*>|$)/sUm', $contents, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)
```

Seems it's work, but I will place a test text later, because I want to know why it wasn't working in first version

Comment: What are you trying to do with the RegEx? Just match or match and replace with something else?

Comment: No, I just want to match some text - headers, and text, and I found my regex stop working on some portion of text. I can't paste text here right now, it's too big, but when I modify regexp as I mentioned it started to work

Comment: original regex looked like this - `'/<a name="dpthd_.*><\/a><a.*><\/a><a.*><\/a><h3.*>(.*)<\/h3>(.*)(?:<a name="dpthd_.*>|$)/sU'`

Comment: Well `(?:` is a non-capturing grouping.  Think the issue is coming with the >|$ at the end also `.*` doesn't match newlines, which can cause issues in HTML matches.

Comment: isn't /s modifier make .* it match newlines?

Comment: `s (PCRE_DOTALL)
    If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Comment: Are you... trying to find stuff in HTML here...? Like... parsing HTML?

Answer (score 4):

Here you have a detailed view of the regexp to comapre :)

**First Regexp**

```
r"""
<a\ name="dpthd_   # Match the characters “<a name="dpthd_” literally
.                  # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
><                 # Match the characters “><” literally
\/                 # Match the character “/” literally
a><a               # Match the characters “a><a” literally
.                  # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
><                 # Match the characters “><” literally
\/                 # Match the character “/” literally
a><a               # Match the characters “a><a” literally
.                  # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
><                 # Match the characters “><” literally
\/                 # Match the character “/” literally
a><h3              # Match the characters “a><h3” literally
.                  # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>                  # Match the character “>” literally
(                  # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   .                  # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
<                  # Match the character “<” literally
\/                 # Match the character “/” literally
h3>                # Match the characters “h3>” literally
(                  # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   .                  # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\s                 # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
   *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(                  # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3
   dpthd              # Match the characters “dpthd” literally
)
"""
```

**Second Regexp**

```
r"""
<a\ name="dpthd_   # Match the characters “<a name="dpthd_” literally
.                  # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
><                 # Match the characters “><” literally
\/                 # Match the character “/” literally
a><a               # Match the characters “a><a” literally
.                  # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
><                 # Match the characters “><” literally
\/                 # Match the character “/” literally
a><a               # Match the characters “a><a” literally
.                  # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
><                 # Match the characters “><” literally
\/                 # Match the character “/” literally
a><h3              # Match the characters “a><h3” literally
.                  # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>                  # Match the character “>” literally
(                  # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   .                  # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
<                  # Match the character “<” literally
\/                 # Match the character “/” literally
h3>                # Match the characters “h3>” literally
(                  # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   .                  # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\s                 # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
   *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
dpthd              # Match the characters “dpthd” literally
"""
```

HTH!

Comment: +1 One of the most detailed explanations in the shortest amount of time that I've seen!

Comment: the regex looks in code like this `preg_match('/<a name="dpthd_.*><\/a><a.*><\/a><a.*><\/a><h3.*>(.*)<\/h3>(.*)(?:<a name="dpthd_.*>|$)/sU', $contents, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)` so slash it's a separator in `/sU'”`

Comment: and `s` and `U` is a modifiers

Comment: i'm not accepting this answer because it's just explaining what regex do and not answering question. i can read all this in manual so i don't actually understand why it has so many upvotes. i'm voting for closing my question because it's too old and i can't find a real answer to it now